# Is DynamoDB's updateitem threadsafe?

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb

If I have a table that looks like the following:

Books {
  author: StringAttribute,
  title: StringAttribute,
  rating: NumberAttribute
}

and I issue two UpdateItem requests concurrently to the same item, one that updates the rating and another that updates the title, is it possible to hit a race condition in which they both succeed but one overwrites the other? Do I need to introduce my own locking in my code?

I've been looking through AWS's docs for something that addresses this scenario but so far have not been able to find anything relevant.

Comment: Its called Optimistic Locking and it is not enabled by default. You should have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, but does DynamoDB not provide any support for this out of the box? I can't find documentation that gives the behavior of the API.

Comment: In the example I provided, I want to update an item's rating and title in separate requests, and if they both succeed, I want the end result to be the new rating and new title.

Comment: Then you should do atomic operations. Like ADD operation (without READ). But if you perform a READ then a SET operation then client side will have out-of-date data and it will overwrite.